# Disable media playback controller coming in the Notification bar using JW player

Tags: android, react-native, jwplayer, jwplayer6, strobe-media-playback

Have integrated JW player for streaming CDN videos in app. Using React native technology for building the code.But as videos are playing on app the media playback controller is coming on notification bar.Please help to resolve this as on closing the notification app is getting crashed

Not able to figure out what is hapenning

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.